# Errors when configuring Apache Airflow to use a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I have been introducing myself to Apache Airflow, so far everything is going well however I have been using the default SQLite database and I now need to change to a PostgreSQL database. I have changed the **executor** to LocalExecutor and I have set the **sql_alchemy_conn** string to *postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow* which is the address of the **airflow** database I created in postgres.

Now when I run `airflow initdb` I recieve the error

`airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite with the LocalExecutor`

I am using postgreSQL 9.4.24

Does anyone know why this is occuring?

Comment: `grep` for `sqlite` in `airflow.cfg` to see whether it is used anywhere.

Comment: Can't find any reference to it

Answer (score 0):

resolved the issue
I was using the wrong postgres user for the location of the database. Should have been using *postgresql+psycopg2://user:user@localhost:5432/airflow*